# I declared an exception handler for validation, but it wasn't used

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-starter

```
[My Package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxSRS.png)
[In 'EmployeeController' class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSfRB.png)
[In package "advice", ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZyRUc.png)
[Postman response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xinnS.png)
```

> I configured an 'ExceptionHandler' to handle exceptions when authentication fails, but when I test it using Postman, I'm not receiving the expected response. "handlerInvalidArgument" doesn't work.

> When I tried moving the handlerInvalidArgument into the EmployeeController, it worked fine.

Comment: try @ControllerAdvice(annotations = RestController.class)

Comment: Please write a proper question, include the code in your question not as offsite links but as text with code tags.